# What is the easy way to delete rows in table for a given specific range?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has two columns, one is FLAG (1 or 0) the other one is INSERT_DATE (format:28/02/2017 23:15:08). In every 5 minutes, an insert statement executes in that table.

I need to delete rows that inserted before 8:00 AM and after 8:00 PM for every day in a month (insert statement executes every day of a mounth in each 5 minutes).

What's the easy way to done it, PSQL, trigger?

Comment: What is the data type of INSERT_DATE?

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, can you write a query that does the delete, no matter how to run it periodically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create some scheduler job for the last day of every month with this command:

```
delete from table1
where extract (hour from insert_date) not between 8 and 19
and trunc(sysdate, 'month') = trunc (insert_date, 'month');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `INSERT_DATE` column is of `DATE` datatype and the month you want to perform the deletion is `2017-02` then you can do:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE  (  EXTRACT( HOUR FROM insert_date ) < 8
       OR EXTRACT( HOUR FROM insert_date ) >= 20 )
AND    DATE '2017-02-01' <= insert_date
AND    insert_date < DATE '2017-03-01';
```